# Is there a better solution instead of ModelMultipleChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-orm, manytomanyfield

I have a form where users can create a fishing trip and they can add multiple participants from the registered users (fishermen).

models.py

```
class Fisherman(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fisherman_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Fisherman"
        verbose_name_plural = "Fishermen"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'

class Trips(models.Model):
    lake = models.CharField("Lake", max_length=150)
    city = models.CharField("City", max_length=100, blank=True)
    s_date = models.DateTimeField("Starting Date", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    e_date = models.DateTimeField("Ending Date", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    fisherman = models.ManyToManyField(Fisherman)
    trip_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    total_catch_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Trip"
        verbose_name_plural = "Trips"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.lake} - {self.trip_id}"
```

forms.py

```
class TripsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fisherman = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Fisherman.objects.all().exclude(user__username="admin"), widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-select'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Trips
        fields = ["lake", "city", "s_date", "e_date", "fisherman"]
        widgets = {
            "lake": forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'LakeInput',}),
            "city": forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'CityInput',}),
            "s_date": forms.DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', attrs={'class':'datetimefield form-control', 'id': 'StartingDate',}),
            "e_date": forms.DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', attrs={'class':'datetimefield form-control', 'id': 'EndingDate',}),
        }
```

I'm currently using ModelMultipleChoiceField that lists all existing fishermen in the form, but I would like to find a better solution because I don't want that users could see all registered fishermen.

Is there a way to add more fishermen to the trip by typing their names? Is it possible in case of manytomanyfield?
I don't know how the "typing solution" could work because only registered fishermen can be added to the trip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like these when there are lots of choices I like to use `django_select2` `ModelSelect2MultipleWidget`.

It loads the options dynamically and has search functionality. More info: https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html